# Alsa driver update in client machine without make

Tags: upgrade, alsa

I have a linux system and updated alsa from 1.0.23 to 1.0.25, It works as expected.

Steps which I performed to compile:

./configure
make 
make install

Now , I have 100's of client machines in which I need to deploy this ALSA update. But, these machine does not have make/setup tools install.

To deploy this update what is the best way?

I even tried creating a package using CHECKINSTALL.

So, with created package I deployed it in 5 machines, in 3 machines the driver got updated and 2 machines reports no information on soundcard.

Am i missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The `alsa-driver` package is outdated; the sound drivers are part of kernel, and are updated by updating the kernel package.

See [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)